# How to transform a dataframe in a plot or a pie chart

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, pie-chart

I have a data frame with two columns and 3 rows and i want transform it to a plot or a pie chart.

I have tried

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Category = c("Pie", "Cake", "IceCream" ), 
  Sales_out = c(28866769.8856, 66292532985.4106, 17328833.4339 )
)

plot(as.factor(Column1§Column2))
```

But it doesnt work

```
plot(as.factor(df$Category),df$Sales_out)
```

It gives Error in df$Category : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: could you provide `dput(df)`?

Comment: dput(df1) 
structure(list(Category = c("Pie", "Cake", "IceCream"
), Sales_out = c(28866769.8856, 66292532985.4106, 17328833.4339
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)) ```

Comment: `pie(df1$Sales_out, df1$Category)`

Comment: or `plot(as.factor(df$Category),df$Sales_out)`

Comment: When I try to do it in a plot it appears: Error in df$Category : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: try with `df1` instead of `df`

Answer (score 0):

If you use plotly you can do the following

For a pie chart:

```
fig = px.pie(df, values='y', names='x', title='Your title')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the difference between your values is too high, which results in a weird pie chart:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Category = c("Pie", "Cake", "IceCream" ), 
  Sales_out = c(28866769.8856, 66292532985.4106, 17328833.4339 )
)

pie(df1$Sales_out, df1$Category, main = "Pie chart")
```

Output:

[image]

When you normalize your data, you can see that the difference is big:

```
[1] 0.0001740913 1.0000000000 0.0000000000
```